# error when using pip to install the glpk library

Tags: python-3.x, visual-c++

When I want to install the glpk library using pip for python on a PC with Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2022 I get the following error, from what I can see, try to compile them as if it were a library in C++, this is because of the commands at the end after the part which says **creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-38\Release\src** everything else is commands to compile using the VS prompt where it seems that you cannot **link 2to3.obj** and **bar.obj** with their respective **2to3.c** and **bar.c** Which raises quite a big doubt in me because I understand that python libraries can contain components in c++ but I understand that they are not linked, let alone generate a **glpk.h.** Below I explain the error that I get using pip

```
`Collecting glpk
  Using cached glpk-0.4.7.tar.gz (161 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: glpk
  Building wheel for glpk (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for glpk (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [15 lines of output]
      WARNING setuptools_scm.pyproject_reading toml section missing 'pyproject.toml does not contain a tool.setuptools_scm section'
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'glpk' extension
      creating build
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-38
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-38\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-38\Release\src
      "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DVERSION_NUMBER=\"\\\"0.4.7\\\"\" -IC:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\include -IC:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Include "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /Tcsrc\2to3.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-38\Release\src\2to3.obj
      2to3.c
      "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DVERSION_NUMBER=\"\\\"0.4.7\\\"\" -IC:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\include -IC:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Include "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /Tcsrc\bar.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-38\Release\src\bar.obj
      bar.c
      C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xq3sgfl_\glpk_043a1a1afc3a47829afe531f4144f1f0\src\lp.h(24): fatal error C1083: No se puede abrir el archivo incluir: 'glpk.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Professional\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.38.33130\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for glpk
Failed to build glpk
ERROR: Could not build wheels for glpk, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects`
```

I already read several answers, such as putting it as an environment variable or downloading it and using Build_WinGLPK.bat in the folder, even one that talked about downloading vs_BuildTools.exe But the truth is that none of them work for me. Any help you can give me?

Answer (score 0):

`glpk` is compatible with
MacOS :: MacOS X and POSIX operating systems. It doesn't have support for Windows OS. See https://pypi.org/project/glpk/#data for more information.